# Is it possible to load an arbitrary shared library file in GDB when analysing a core dump?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

As a hobby I reverse engineer the server executables of my favourite games. In this instance I am trying to debug (and patch fix) a server crash. I have mapped out several structures in memory and would like to inspect them cleanly in GDB. My intention is to do something as the following (replace ebp with the address, of course, this is just an example illustrate the problem):

```
print *(UsefulDebug::Structures::StructureOne*)(ebp+8)
```

Where `UsefulDebug::Structures::StructureOne` is defined in the debug information of my shared library.

I have tried to rename my "debug library" to match one of the shared library objects loaded at the time of the crash. When doing so, I find that GDB can auto-complete my debug information, but ptype and any printing does not recognise it after the second namespace. Here's an actual example:

```
(gdb) ptype NWNXLib
type = namespace NWNXLib
(gdb) ptype NWNXLib::API
type = namespace NWNXLib::API
(gdb) ptype NWNXLib::API::CExoString
No type "API" within class or namespace "NWNXLib"
```

Given the following files ...

```
server_executable: This is the executable which crashed.

core: This is the core dump produced when the above executable crashed.

useful_shared_library.so: This is an arbitrary file which contains debug information for all of the structures present in the program.
```

Is it possible for me to use the debug information present in **useful_shared_library.so** while debugging the core dump, even though that library has nothing to do with the crash and wasn't loaded at the time? There may also be an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do. If there is, I would love to hear it!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try `add-symbol-file useful_shared_library.so 0`

Comment: @immibis Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that, and in the same way that renaming the shared library to one already loaded allowed me to resolve two namespaces but *not* the structures, even though GDB auto-completes it, so too does it fail here.

Comment: Update on this: using the `add-symbol-file` method I was able to make this work, with one caveat: the namespaces must be enclosed in single quotations. For example, `p **('NWNXLib::API::CServerExoApp'**)($ebp + 8)` rather than `p **(NWNXLib::API::CServerExoApp**)($ebp + 8)`. When debugging a core dump which has these symbols loaded the single quotations aren't necessary.